# capturing one audio sample from a usb input thread (microphone) with python

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, usb

Currently, I'm launching my main program that controls when I launch the speaker and mic threads. From there I can also control mute/unmute on the device (a usb headset), etc. The audio threads are in a separate file in a an audio class.

This code works. Right now it captures an audio sample at a particular loop count that is pre-set. I would prefer to grab an audio sample whenever requested from the main program, but I have not had any success at setting a flag and checking it in the mic thread. I would get pyaudio errors, like overflow/underflow.

I would appreciate if somebody would suggest a technique to grab audio input samples (mic data). thanks

```
def openTheMic(self, **kwargs):
        # script can over-ride any value in the myAudio __init__
        print ("***in openTheMic ***")

        # picks up values passed by the test_script and maps them to myAudio class,
        # otherwise will use defaults set in class
        for (k,v) in kwargs.iteritems():
            #print("k = %s, v = %s" % (k,v))
            setattr(self, myAudio._map[k], v)

        stream = self.p.open(
            format = self.FORMAT,
            channels = self.CHANNELS,
            rate = self.RATE,
            input = True,
            output = True,
            frames_per_buffer = self.CHUNK
        )

        setMicThreadStartTime(time.time())
        print("time @ start of mic thread is: %s" % time.time())
        starttime = time.time()
        while myAudio.openTheMicThreadActive == True:            
            for i in range(0, 1200):
                data = stream.read(self.CHUNK)
                captureCount = 1000

                if i == captureCount:
                    currentData = data
                    # abort the mic and spkr threads
                    myAudio.openTheMicThreadActive = False
                    myAudio.playDeadAirThreadActive = False
                    print("i is: %i: " % (i))
                    # set a global variable to get the data to the main program
                    setAudioData(currentData)
                    print("capture time: i = %s, time is %s " % (i, time.time()))


        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        print ("***closed the stream in openTheMic *** and the time is: %s" % time.time())
        self.p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

This method worked, but intermittently with overflow/underflow issues, but those problems disappeared once I set the mic sample rate to 16kHz instead of the default. I changed the code a little so that I can take a sample at any time from the main program by using a global flag var that the mic loop checks to know if it should grab a sample or not.